# Installing qt5 hangs when installing headless with xvfb-run via ssh connection using official .run installer

Tags: software-installation, ssh, qt, qt5

I have a problem with trying to install QT. I am following the instructions from http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html and from their source `provision.sh` I'm using these commands to try and install QT5 via the offline installer provided on the qt website

```
curl -L -o /downloads/qt-installer.run \
               http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.9.1.run && \
    chmod +x /downloads/qt-installer.run && \
    xvfb-run /downloads/qt-installer.run
```

Since I'm trying to install via a remote computer, I have to use xvfb-run to try to install it headless, however when I run `xvfb-run /downloads/qt-installer.run` my command line just hangs after some prompts and I have no clue what they mean and from hours of googling, I can't seem to wrap my head arround what I'm supposed to do or what I'm doing wrong.

Heres what it outputs:

```
xvfb-run /downloads/qt-installer.run
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
[106] Warning: Unsupported screen format: depth: 8, red_mask: 0, blue_mask: 0
[115] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
[115] Warning: QPainter::setCompositionMode: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[115] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[115] Warning: QPainter::deviceTransform: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[115] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[115] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[115] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[115] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setClipRect: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[115] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[115] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[115] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[115] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setClipRect: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[115] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[116] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[116] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[116] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[116] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::translate: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setClipRect: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[116] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
[116] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[116] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[116] Warning: QPainter::deviceTransform: Painter not active
[116] Warning: QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::drawPoints: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::drawPoints: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QPainter::pen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
[117] Warning: QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
[117] Warning: QPainter::save: Painter not active
[117] Warning: QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with a script file passed in as seen in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105269/silent-install-qt-run-installer-on-ubuntu-server

I was able to install qt inside a docker image using a similar command.

```
xvfb-run /downloads/qt-installer.run --script qt-install-noninteractive.qs
```